# Does profanity in URLs get flagged in any way?

Tags: discussion, imgur, profanity

I just uploaded an image using the Imgur Stack Exchange uploader. The URL it provided for the image contains a swear word.

Does this get automatically flagged? Should I reupload?

In addition, should this be reported as a bug?

Comment: Now I'm just curious what the offensive URL was.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCUNt.png)

Comment: Remove link, try upload again.  If the word is still there, perhaps it's the system trying to tell you something?

Answer (score 6):

1. Don't worry that type of auto flagging doesn't happen. Some people do run bots to look but they generally avoid common URLs like that and in any case flagging relies on users explicitly casting offensive flags. And,
2. Even if that did happen, mods are sane-ish people. Nobody's going to hold a random imgur URL against anybody.

If it bothers you, just giggle then re-upload the image. But nothing obligates you to do that. Random letters sometimes making words in URLs is basically just an amusing fact of life.

Sorry if brief, on phone.

Comment: "*mods are sane people*" - I strongly object to being called sane :-P

Comment: @rand Yes I cringed a little when I typed that. Fixed. :P

Comment: Brief answers are the best, no much to read. :-)

Comment: I strongly object to rand being called "people".